# What am I doing wrong in this probability exercise?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

In the experiment of throwing a die $n$ successive times, what's the probability of observing two consecutive 3's?

The consecutive threes can be observed in the first and the second throw, in the second and third throw, in the third and fourth throw, in the fourth and fifth throw, ..., and in the (n-1)-th and n-th throw. I would say these combinations account for $(n-1)*6^{n-2}$ favorable outcomes out of a total of $6^{n}$ different possibilities.

Then, I concluded the answer had to be something like $(n-1)*6^{n-2}$ over $6^{n}$.

Where does my argument go astray?

Thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: Having a three in rolls one and two and having a three in rolls two and three are **not** mutually exclusive events. (Neither are they independent events.)

Comment: The point is, that  there is a possibility of many consecutive $3$s, in which case two or more of the events that you mention will occur simultaneously. Consequently, the sum of the above probabilities forms an upper bound for the desired probability, but due to non-empty intersections is not the right answer.

Comment: If the problem were about observing EXACTLY two threes, would the corresponding version of my argument be fine? I believe in that case I would obtain a probability of $(n-1)5^{n-2}/6^{n}$.

Comment: Yes, the probability for the EXACTLY two threes case is correct. Did you find the general probability for the AT LEAST two threes case?

Comment: No, I was not taking into account the failure of mutual exclusivity mentioned by Lord Shark. Now that I see what it is that I was doing wrong, I will give it another try

Comment: What about $33*3$ where $*\neq3$?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that thre are only $3$ dice. In how many cases can we have $2$ consecutive $3$'s? In the following cases (I shall use $*$ to denote something that is *not* a $3$):

- $33*$;
- $*33$;
- $333$.

Do you see the problem now? You missed the $333$ possibility.

Comment: If the problem were about observing EXACTLY two threes, would the corresponding version of my argument be fine? I believe in that case I would obtain a probability of $(n−1)5^{n-2}/6^{n}$?

Comment: @Jamai-Con Indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the probability for the "EXACTLY two $3$s" case is correct: 
$$\underbrace{(n-1)}_{\text{positions of $33$}}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2}_{\text{probability of $33$}}\cdot\underbrace{\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n-2}}_{\text{probability of the rest}}=\frac{(n-1)5^{n-2}}{6^n}.$$
As regards the "AT LEAST two $3$s" case, note that in $\{3,*\}^n$ there are 
$\binom{n-k+1}{k}$ strings with $k$ $3$s where $33$ never occurs. Hence the probability is
$$1-\frac{1}{6^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lceil n/2\rceil}\binom{n-k+1}{k}5^{n-k}.$$
For example, for $n=3$, the above formula yields: $11/6^3$ (note that $33*\to 5$,$*33\to 5$,$333\to 1$, $5+5+1=11$).

Comment: Thanks.........